# bind FontColor from other element on same hierarchy height

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to change the color of the color of any `Path` when I hover another element like some text.

Both elements are on the same hierarchy height. They are placed inside a `WrapPanel`.

```
<WrapPanel>
    <Path Data="{StaticResource Email}" Fill="{Binding ??}"/>
    <TextBlock>Einstellungen</TextBlock>
</WrapPanel>
```

How can I bind the `Fill` property of the `Path` to the `Foreground` Property of the `TextBlock`? Is it possible without using an `x:Name`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use `Name`?

Comment: @Derp because I have about 20 different Buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
<WrapPanel>
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,        
AncestorType={x:Type WrapPanel}}}"/>
        <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,        
AncestorType={x:Type WrapPanel}}, Path=Tag,Mode=OneWayToSource}">Sample</TextBlock>
    </WrapPanel>
```